How do I show the max value of a column and show all rows using Oracle SQL
I have a table POLICIES that has data like this:
POLICY NAME  VERSION NUMBER
Policy ABC   1.0
Policy ABC   1.1
Policy ABC   2.0
Policy DEF   1.0
Policy DEF   1.5
Policy GHI   1.0
Policy GHI   2.0
Policy GHI   3.2

What I'm wanting to see is the latest (highest) version number in a separate column, so I know what is current. The assumption being that the highest version number is the current version.
POLICY NAME  VERSION NUMBER  CURRENT VERSION
Policy ABC              1.0              2.0
Policy ABC              1.1              2.0
Policy ABC              2.0              2.0
Policy DEF              1.0              1.5
Policy DEF              1.5              1.5
Policy GHI              1.0              3.2
Policy GHI              2.0              3.2
Policy GHI              3.2              3.2

My SQL skills are basic to say the least, and so far the closest I've come is this:
select Policy_Name, Version_Number, max(Version_Number) AS Current_Version
from POLICIES
group by Policy_Name, Version_Number;

which gives me this:
POLICY NAME  VERSION NUMBER  CURRENT VERSION
Policy ABC              1.0              1.0
Policy ABC              1.1              1.1
Policy ABC              2.0              2.0
Policy DEF              1.0              1.0
Policy DEF              1.5              1.5
Policy GHI              1.0              1.0
Policy GHI              2.0              2.0
Policy GHI              3.2              3.2

I'm thinking I want a subquery to find the max value for each policy_name, but I can't quite figure it out.

Use the MAX analytic function:
SELECT policy_name,
       version_number,
       MAX(version_number) OVER (PARTITION BY policy_name) AS current_version
FROM   policies;

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE policies (POLICY_NAME, VERSION_NUMBER) AS
SELECT 'Policy ABC', CAST('1.0' AS VARCHAR2(10)) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Policy ABC', '1.1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Policy ABC', '2.0' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Policy DEF', '1.0' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Policy DEF', '1.5' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Policy GHI', '1.0' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Policy GHI', '2.0' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Policy GHI', '3.2' FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



POLICY_NAME
VERSION_NUMBER
CURRENT_VERSION




Policy ABC
1.0
2.0


Policy ABC
1.1
2.0


Policy ABC
2.0
2.0


Policy DEF
1.0
1.5


Policy DEF
1.5
1.5


Policy GHI
1.0
3.2


Policy GHI
2.0
3.2


Policy GHI
3.2
3.2




However, version numbers are not numbers and version 3.11 is typically considered to be later than version 3.3 so you may want to split the version number into its major and minor parts and take the latest of those when finding the maximum:
SELECT policy_name,
       version_number,
       MAX(version_number) KEEP (
         DENSE_RANK LAST
         ORDER BY TO_NUMBER(
                    SUBSTR(version_number, 1, INSTR(version_number, '.') - 1)
                  ),
                  TO_NUMBER(
                    SUBSTR(version_number, INSTR(version_number, '.') + 1)
                  )
       ) OVER (PARTITION BY policy_name) AS current_version
FROM   policies;

Which if you add some extra data:
INSERT INTO policies (policy_name, version_number)
SELECT 'Policy GHI', '11.23' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Policy GHI', '11.100' FROM DUAL;

Then outputs:



POLICY_NAME
VERSION_NUMBER
CURRENT_VERSION




Policy ABC
1.0
2.0


Policy ABC
1.1
2.0


Policy ABC
2.0
2.0


Policy DEF
1.0
1.5


Policy DEF
1.5
1.5


Policy GHI
1.0
11.100


Policy GHI
2.0
11.100


Policy GHI
3.2
11.100


Policy GHI
11.23
11.100


Policy GHI
11.100
11.100



fiddle

Thanks, this is exactly what I needed, particularly the last part because there are values where the decimal place is multiple digits. The last query you provided solves for that situation.
